# Does vee-validate work with third-party UI components, e.g. of Primevue?

Tags: javascript, validation, dropdown, vee-validate

I am using vee-validate v4.0, vue's (v3) components with TypeScript and UI components from Primevue and Ionic. Validation on simple input fields works fine:

```
<template> 
...
<Field
  v-slot="{ field }"
  v-model="username"
  :rules="isRequired"
  name="username"
>
  <IonInput
    v-bind="field"
    type="text"
  />
</Field>
<ErrorMessage
  name="username"
  class="error"
/>
...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
...
 methods: {
    isRequired (value: string) {
      if (!value) {
        return 'This field is required'
      }
      return true
    }
  }
...
</script>
```

Applying the same to Primevue's [Dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/dropdown) element fails:

```
<Field
  v-slot="{ field }"
  v-model="campaign"
  name="campaign"
  :rules="isRequired"
>
  <Dropdown
    :options="campaigns"
    option-value="id"
    option-label="name"
    placeholder="Choose a campaign"
    v-bind="field"
  />
</Field>
<ErrorMessage
  name="campaign"
  class="error"
/>
```

Validation works as expected, but opening the Dropdown leads to error messages:

[image]

**Do you know how this can be solved? Is there an example how vee-validate works with more complex fields like dropdown or multiselect elements?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by listening on the input/change events and passing data between `<Field>` and (in this special case Primevue's) `<Dropdown>` as follows:

```
<Form v-slot="{ errors }" @submit="saveAndProceed()">
...

  <Field
    v-slot="{ field }"
    v-model="campaign"
    name="campaign"
    value="value"
    :rules="isRequired"
  >
    <Dropdown
      :options="campaigns"
      option-value="id"
      option-label="name"
      placeholder="Choose a campaign"
      :model-value="field.value"
      :class="{ 'p-invalid': errors.campaign }"
      @input="field.onInput.forEach((fn) => fn($event.value))"
      @change="field.onChange.forEach((fn) => fn($event.value))"
    />
    <ErrorMessage
      name="campaign"
      class="error"
    />
  </Field>
...
</Form>
```

Compare also with the following references for other events (onBlur etc.):

- [Vee-validate's Field reference](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field#slots)
- E.g., [Primevue's Dropdown events](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@update:modelValue="handleChange"` to your dropdown:

```
<Field
  v-slot="{ field, handleChange }"
  v-model="campaign"
  name="campaign"
  :rules="isRequired"
>
  <Dropdown
    :options="campaigns"
    option-value="id"
    option-label="name"
    placeholder="Choose a campaign"
    v-bind="field"
    @update:modelValue="handleChange"
  />
</Field>
<ErrorMessage
  name="campaign"
  class="error"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div class="col-6">
              <Field
                v-slot="{ field,handleChange }"
                v-model="brand_name"
                name="brand_name"
>
                <div class="p-col-6">
                    <div class="p-inputgroup">
                      <Dropdown
                          :options="brands"
                          optionLabel="name"
                          optionValue="code"
                          :model-value="field.value"
                          placeholder="Select car brand"
                          @update:modelValue="handleChange"
                          
                      />
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
              </Field>
             
               
            </div>
```